# Split a text file with customize name and size

Tags: split

I use Debian and I have a text file and I want to split that into several files with specific suffix name and size. I want split that file by n chunk therefore, I should use -n option. How can I do that with split command? Thanks

Comment: Split it by what , paragraphs, lines or something else ? Do you want to do the splitting in the text editor or in the terminal ?

Comment: Perhaps you can give us a sample suffix name and size so that answerers can get close to an actual Answer for you?

Comment: Also; what operating system are you using? [POSIX split](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/split.html) does not allow for a custom suffix (natively).

Comment: Thanks dears, I edited my post.

Comment: Any reason you can't just first use `split` with specific size, and then rename all of them afterwards? For example with `rename` from the Debian package `rename` (which can rename multiple files at once, according to a pattern).

Comment: So I can't split the file into specific size and specific suffix name simultaneously with split command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With split (GNU coreutils) you could split `file` into `N` chunks `split00.part`, `split01.part`, ... `split[N-1].part`:

- by size - lines can be splitted "into two halves", but all parts have the same size

  ```
  split -d -nN --additional-suffix=.part file split
  ```
- at whole lines/records - parts may slightly differ in size

  ```
  split -d -nl/N --additional-suffix=.part file split
  ```
- or split by defined size of chunks in bytes like 1MiB

  ```
  split -d -b1048576 --additional-suffix=.part file split
  ```

Comment: The first command was what I need. Thanks Freddy